# Consuming WCF return value of List(Of String) in WinForms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, wcf

I've just started to get rid of Web Services and implement WCF instead. But once I tried to add the following method with a List(Of String) return value, my WCF ServiceReference - which was added successfully - had became unreadable in my WinForms client application code. i.e. It was not defined.

The scenario is pretty simple:
I am creating an OperationContract named ServerMessages with a list of string return value.
This is the interface:

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface ICommunicationHandler
<OperationContract()>
    Function ServerMessages() As List(Of String)
End Interface
```

And there is the implementation class:

```
    Public Class CommunicationHandler
        Implements ICommunicationHandler

        Public Function ServerMessages() As List(Of String) _
 Implements ICommunicationHandler.ServerMessages
            Dim messages As New List(Of String)
            messages.Add("First Message")
            messages.Add("Second Message")
            Return messages
        End Function
    End Class
```

There is my client application code:

```
Dim locServ As New LocalReference.CommunicationHandlerClient
TextBox1.Text += "First Server Messages:" & vbLf & locaServ.ServerMessages(0)
```

I've tried removing the service reference from the project and re-adding it, but this doesn't solved the problem. On the other hand, removing that specific method ServerMessages() makes the ServiceReference available again in my code. I've even tried to define the type List(Of String) in the Service Interface by adding this attribute:

```
<ServiceKnownType(GetType(List(Of String)), ServiceContract()>
```

but nothing had changed.

---

EDIT

I've noticed this warning in the client application Error window:

> Warning 2 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port Detail: There
>   was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent
>   on. XPath to wsdl:binding:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='BasicHttpBinding_ICommunicationHandler']
>   XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:service[@name='CommunicationHandler']/wsdl:port[@name='BasicHttpBinding_ICommunicationHandler']   D:\WCTApp\Service
>   References\LocalReference\Reference.svcmap

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set the Collection Type to be System.Collection.Generic.List in the configuration of the web reference?

Comment: Yes, Steve. I tried that too. But unfortunately it didn't helped.

Comment: I've added to the original post a warning message that I've noticed  in the client application Error list.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by unchecking the [Reuse types in referenced assemblies] in the WCF ServiceReference configuration of my client application. Thanks Steve for letting me having another check on it.

The problem - in this case - was that I've added some references in the service (Google Drive references) which was not defined in my application and therefore causing the ServiceReference not to read the service appropriately. Since I decided not to use these references, I should had eliminated them both from my client application as well as the WCF Service. Now that I stopped using these references in my client application, everything worked as it is supposed to be.

This was my mistake but maybe someone else will fall into the exact same issue and find this situation helpful.